# java concurrent ordered response buffer

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, grpc-java, java-websocket

i have a stream of messages coming from a websocket or a grpc client. for each message my service produces 0 or more reply messages. by default both websocket endpoints and grpc request observers are guaranteed to be called by maximum 1 thread concurrently, so my replies are sent in the same order as requests. Now I want to dispatch request processing to other threads and process them in parallel, but still keep the order. Therefore, I need some "concurrent ordered response buffer", which will buffer replies to a given request message until processing of previous requests is finished and replies to them are sent (in order they were produced within each "request bucket").
I can develop such  class myself, but it seems a common case, so I was wondering if maybe such thing already exists (to not reinvent the wheel). however I could not easily find anything on the web: does anyone knows about something like this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in case someone needs it also, I've written it myself due to lack of answers:

https://github.com/morgwai/java-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/pl/morgwai/base/util/concurrent/OrderedConcurrentOutputBuffer.java

feedback is welcome :)